# Is there a VueJS component that mimic's http://jsfiddle.net/NuWna/2/

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm looking for a VueJS Card Component that mimic's this Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NuWna/2/

Having a hard time writing the jQuery code in VueJS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slide").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("div.snipit").slideDown("slow");
    },function(){
        $(this).find("div.snipit").slideUp("slow");    
    });


});
```

Comment: sure its not complicated to make in vue  the same

Comment: Well then please look using a web search engine, this is not what SO is meant for. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Maciej ... I've been searching and continue to search. I don't need to read anything...  just need help... That IS what SO is for! If you not going to help DONT COMMENT!

Comment: Why ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483366/is-there-a-vuejs-component-that-mimics-http-jsfiddle-net-nuwna-2

Comment: Totally agree @RecardoPoole - too many people on here offer criticism but no help, it's a waste of typing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Vue component and you can use jQuery slideUp/slideDown methods on `mounted` vue lifecycle hooks,

Also I've given solution without jQuery below.

**1. Using Vue + jQuery** - http://jsfiddle.net/79rc5oss/1/

```js
Vue.component('my-comp', {
 template: `
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x200" alt="1" width="250" height="200" />
    <div class="snipit">
         <h4>Image 1</h4>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
  `,
  mounted: function(){
   $(".slide").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("div.snipit").slideDown("slow");
    },function(){
        $(this).find("div.snipit").slideUp("slow");    
    });
  }
  
})

var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app'
});
```

```css
img{
    border:1px solid yellow;   
    margin: 14px 0 0 0;
}

div.slide {
    width: 310px;
    height: 230px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/310x230) no-repeat top center;

}

div.slide div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border:1px solid red;
    bottom: 14px;
    left:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-comp></my-comp>

</div>
```

**2. Using Vue + CSS without jQuery** - http://jsfiddle.net/79rc5oss/

```js
Vue.component('my-comp', {
 template: `
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x200" alt="1" width="250" height="200" />
    <div class="snipit">
         <h4>Image 1</h4>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
  `
  
})

var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app'
});
```

```css
img{
    border:1px solid yellow;   
    margin: 14px 0 0 0;
}

div.slide {
    width: 310px;
    height: 230px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/310x230) no-repeat top center;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.slide div.snipit{
    width: 250px;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border:1px solid red;
    bottom: 12px;
    left:30px;
    overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
    
}


.slide:hover div.snipit{
  height: 100px;
  
 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-comp></my-comp>

</div>
```